# Suggestion of research papers

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, hopf-algebras

I’m trying to find the research papers related to Hopf algebra over non commutative polynomial rings  O( M_n(H)) 
to get concrete understanding about it. But unfortunately I couldn’t find any favorable research paper about it.seeking for your help in this regard ...
Thank you

Comment: Hi Sania Asif, please be a bit more specific. What is $H$ for you? What is $M_n(H)$? Are you looking for Hopf algebra *structures* on this $O(M_n(H))$ or for Hopf *$O(M_n(H))$-algebras*?

Comment: Hi Ender, H is a non commutative ring , e.g, ring of quaternions. I am looking for Hopf algebra structure for O( M_n(H)) = polynomials of matrices over quaternions.